# How many projects do you work on concurrently?

Tags: gm.general-mathematics, soft-question

I was wondering how many concurrent research projects a typical math researcher works on at a given time. I ask because I currently have the oppertunity to start a second project on something I'm fairly familiar with (background reading-wise). One of the main reasons I'm considering taking in a second project is because the first one is going rather slowly (I've hit a roadblock which is potentially insurmountable). If you do work on multiple projects, do you tend to jump between them the moment you get stuck or do you dedicate your full attention to one of them, for say, a week? What's your secret to staying productive?

Just to be specific, let's limit "projects" to writing (contributing to) papers you intend to publish in the near future. As well, "working on" should be interpreted as dedicating a sizable chunk of your time to researching the problem at hand. I do not wish to count projects that you put aside for more than a few weeks until you have an inspiration.

I understand the question is somewhat subjective and the obvious answer is that it depends on the person in question. The way I see it is when you work on multiple problems, part of the reason is that you are hedging your bets on which problem will end up solved. However, I'm just interested in the overall average (which im guessing has little variance) and more importantly whether it's bigger than 1.

Comment: Curiously, why has this question been closed?

Comment: While I don't like the decision I am not surprised by it;
there is a somewhat widespread general dislike of this type of question, and the fact that you made the question quite personal and perhaps too playful (bragging rights and so on) might have contributed. Also, I think it should be CW.

Yet, what I find truly surprising is that it got a downvote without comment. 

Comment: Thanks. The bragging part was a playful addition, but I see what you mean. I'll take it out

Comment: How many? Probably too many!

Comment: Sorry, I should have left a comment more promptly (had to run off to a short meeting).  If you want a pointer to specific spot in the FAq, I would say the problem is that it does not permit a precise answer.  Setting aside the question of who "you" is, whether one is working on a project is a pretty tricky question.  I also wonder what you're really going to learn from the answers to such a question.  Some people focus on one thing for years, some people flit from project to project and have their fingers in a lot of pies.  You have to figure out what's right for you.

Comment: But as for your final question, I would actually guess the variance is quite large (it certainly has been for me over the course of my career), and that the average is much bigger than one.

Comment: @Alex: you can always start a discussion on meta if you would like to change the closers minds, but quite frankly I don't see the value in the question. There is so much variability in what one would define as "working" and ways to split up or regroup projects that I can't imagine that the answers will be useful (never mind how much time you spend trying to define the parameters of your question). Also, I doubt the answers would be very candid.

Comment: @Ben Webster: I would think that this has a fairly concrete answer based on the restriction of actively contributing to a paper in progress. For example, I could ask "how many classes did you take concurrently in grad school" and the typical answer might be 3-5. The reason I ask my question is I honestly don't know what a good number is for research. It's not like a class, where I just do homework and study for tests. Experience says it's much more time consuming. 

Comment: I'm afraid surveys of the crowd are not in the scope of MathOverflow.  You might ask if there have been studies or surveys in the past.

Comment: 4                                        .